# Runtime Warning directed to stderr when running QProcess

Tags: python, c++, qt5, runtime, stderr

I am executing a Python script within a Qt project (C++) and there is a runtime warning about an array containing NaN values.  This isn't a showstopper for executing the Python code outside of the project and it creates the file I need from it.  However, my QProcess object is connected to a signal to read both stdout and stderr and the warning is directed as stderr; this stops the QProcess prematurely and the Python script is aborted and the needed output file never created.  I have one fix in mind where I leave connecting to stderr/stdout signals as an option with a boolean argument, but I'd rather find another option.  Is there anyway within Qt to redirect warnings to stdout or ignore completely?  I checked my project file and there is no -Werror flag for the compiler.

Comment: Please show your code -- preferably in the form of a [mcve].  Specifically, the statement `"...my QProcess object is connected to a signal to read both stdout and stderr and the warning is directed as stderr; this stops the QProcess prematurely..."` doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.